# Scroll a scrollview endlessly

Tags: android, scrollview

I have the following custom horizontal scroll view. The problem is that it only scrolls fully from right to left but not from left to right direction i.e. when image set to its original place scrolling in one side is done. I want to move this in both direction equally.

```
 <com.custom
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/outerScroll1"
                android:layout_width="1500dip"
                android:layout_height="200dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scrollX="300dip"
                >
    <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="1500dip"
                      android:layout_height="200dip" 
                      >
                  <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="500dip"
                        android:layout_height="200dip"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@drawable/pic"
                         />
                </RelativeLayout>

           </com.custom>
```

I tried sliding drawer but didn't work. Even I use  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in custom view but these change the position of view i.e slides it.

Comment: Could you send your java codes where you scroll the scrollView too?